# How do I allow incoming TCP Traffic on a Port in CentOS 6.7?

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6

I am trying to configure a R Shiny Server on CentOS 6.7, and I need to allow incoming TCP traffic on Port 3838.

I am new to Linux and was wondering how I can modify my settings to allow incoming traffic on Port 3838?

Answer (score 0):

This is command for the your question.

> /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s ( source ip range) -p tcp --dport 3838 -j
>   ACCEPT

where source ip mean machine from where you want to access the port